# Better way to calculate the SUM of one, two and three consecutive items

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sum

**class**

```
public class myItem
{
    public int ID;
    public long Value;
    public long Sum1;
    public long Sum2;
    public long Sum3;
}
```

**data**

```
ID   Value
1    25
2    45
3    56
4    21
```

**result:**

```
     Sum1     Sum2         Sum3
1    25     25 + 45    25 + 45 + 56
2    45     45 + 56    45 + 56 + 21
3    56     56 + 21    56 + 21 + 0
4    21     21 + 0     21 +  0 + 0
```

**Current procedure:** Works but very slow (~10 minutes) with 100k rows.

```
List<myItem> list;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
{
   myItem m = list[i];
   m.Sum1 = list.Where(x => x.ID == i).Sum(x => x.Value);
   m.Sum2 = list.Where(x => x.ID >= i && x.ID <= i + 2).Sum(x => x.Value);
   m.Sum3 = list.Where(x => x.ID >= i && x.ID <= i + 3).Sum(x => x.Value);
}
```

So I guess there should be a way to do it without the `for` to speed things up.

Comment: Are the items in `list` in order?  If not sort them and just use the index for the sums `m.Sum2 = list[i].Value + list[i+1].Value;`  all you have to do is add checks for when `i +1` and `i +2` are larger than the size of `list`.

Comment: This is incredibly inefficent, but it's not due to your use of `for` loop. You're using `list.Where(...)` three times for every row, which has to search the entire list for every query. Why don't you just directly reference the `myItem` objects that you want relative to the index `i` you're currently on?

Comment: You're also calling `list.Count()` for every iteration of the loop, if the list isn't changing, hoisting the count will help. You can also fake it by adding two `0` values to the end, going to `i - 2`, then removing the extras so the sums are always of 3 values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause of the slowness is that your loop is O(n^2), since for each element you search the entire list for its successors. Below reduces that to O(n log n) (slowest part is the sort).

```
List<myItem> list;
list.Sort(<.. sort by id ..>);
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
   myItem m = list[i];
   m.Sum1 = m.Value;

   m.Sum2 = m.Sum1;
   if (i < list.Count - 1)
   {
       m.Sum2 += list[i + 1].Value;
   }

   m.Sum3 = m.Sum2;
   if (i < list.Count - 2)
   {
       m.Sum3 = += list[i + 2].Value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Use the `Count` property, not the `Enumerable.Count()` extension method. Also, your second `if` should be `-2`, correct?

Comment: OK. I see what you did, just need some change, because last row need  `{21, 21 + 0, 21 + 0 + 0 }`

Comment: @Eris: Though I agree about using the `Count` property, it's worth noting that `Enumerable.Count()` will use the `Count` property under the covers when the source is an `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

(undeleting answer, because it turns out the other answers still have subtle bugs in them)

LINQ is not helping you on this one. Just reference the array indexes as needed:

```
List<myItem> list;

// sort list by id
list.Sort(t => t.ID);

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
   myItem m = list[i];

   m.Sum1 = m.Value;
   m.Sum2 = m.Sum1 + (i + 1 < list.Count ? list[i + 1].Value : 0);
   m.Sum3 = m.Sum2 + (i + 2 < list.Count ? list[i + 2].Value : 0);
}
```

**EDIT: Little side note about list.Count() vs list.Count**

I notice that there are comments about not using `list.Count()` (`Enumerable.Count()`) in favor of `list.Count` (the property).  I personally like that as well, but it should be noted that, unlike some may be led to believe, the `Enumerable.Count()` version **will not** iterate the whole list to get the count. Instead, because it detects that the list is an implementation of `ICollection<T>`, it will use the `Count` property directly. So really, the performance difference between the two options ***in this specific case***, is negligible.

This behavior is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx).

> If the type of *source* implements `ICollection<T>`, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method determines the count.

Answer (score 2):

Just making some modifications to Jared's solution but using his idea:

```
        List<myItem> list;
        //list.Sort(<.. sort by id ..>);
        int count = list.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            myItem m = list[i];
            m.Sum1 = m.Value;                
            m.Sum2 = (i+1 < count) ? (m.Value + list[i+1].Value) : m.Value;
            m.Sum3 = (i+2 < count) ? (m.Sum2 + list[i+2].Value) : m.Sum2;                
        }
```

Comment: As @eris said. Instead of using `list.Count()` method, just call `list.Count` property.

Answer (score 0):

Functional way here:

```
var seed = new { 
    Result = new List<myItem>(), 
    Item1 = ( myItem )null, 
    Item2 = ( myItem )null 
};
// seed contains intermediate result and other items related to currentItem
// [Item1, Item2, currentItem]
// For the first item, it would be
// [null, null, Id = 1]
// For the second item, it would be
// [null, Id = 1, Id = 2]
// And the third
// [Id = 1, Id = 2, Id = 3]
// For nth item, it's
// [Id = n-2, Id = n-1, Id = n]
var final = input.Aggregate( seed, ( pr, i ) =>
{
    if ( pr.Item1 != null )
    {
        var item1 = pr.Item1;
        item1.Sum3 = item1.Sum2 + i.Value;
    }

    if ( pr.Item2 != null )
    {
        var item2 = pr.Item2;
        item2.Sum2 = item2.Sum1 + i.Value;
    }

    pr.Result.Add( i );
    i.Sum1 = i.Value;
    // It will create lots of short life object.
    // If performance is bad, create named class just as this anonymous class,
    // update its properties and return it
    // pr.Item1 = pr.Item2;
    // pr.Item2 = pr.i;
    // return pr;
    return new { Result = pr.Result, Item1 = pr.Item2, Item2 = i };
} );
```

Comment: Ok, seem on the right track, but you need add some explanation. Not sure how you reference next items

Comment: It doesn't reference next items, but reference back previous two items if there are.

Comment: And what is `input.Aggregate` ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. No sort needed. Not sure if it would run faster please check.

```
list.ForEach(m =>
{
      m.Sum1 = m.Value;
      m.Sum2 = ((m.ID + 1) < list.Count) ? (m.Sum1 + list[m.ID + 1].Value) : m.Sum1;
      m.Sum3 = ((m.ID + 2) < list.Count) ? (m.Sum2 + list[m.ID + 2].Value) : m.Sum2;
});
```